# totally remove particular div in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

this is my html

```
<div id="lan">
<a href="#">Nl</a><a href="#">En</a>
</div>
```

this is my css try

```
@media all and (max-width: 980px) { 
    #lan{
        display:none;
    }   
}
```

if i try this above css then div is not visible in mobile view, that is ok but when i see in inspect element that particular div is available there, i dont want to show this in inspect element also. i want to delete it totally.

this is my javascript try

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 700px)');

if(mq.matches) {

    $(function(){
        $('#lan').remove();
    });

}
```

The above code show me an error like this

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
    (index):420Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
        at (index):420
    (anonymous) @ (index):420
```

What should i do?

Comment: does it work?: `if(mq.matches) { $('#lan').remove();}`

Comment: Can you make a plunkr or fiddler :)

Comment: not working @Banzay

Comment: @VishalPanara Does it work if you use jQuery instead of $ alias? `if(mq.matches) { jQuery('#lan').remove(); }`

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev Great...! Its working, Thank you brother

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var width = screen.width,
        height = screen.height;
 
        if (screen.width <= 320 || screen.height <= 176) {
  
  $('#lan').remove();
        }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
<div id="lan">
<a href="#">Nl</a><a href="#">En</a>
</div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot remove the `div`, I suggest getting its parent element.